Can I be sure which copy of a dependency is used in war containing an uberjar?
An application is deployed as a war file. It contains a dependency "a" as a jar file inside the war file. "a" has its own dependency "b", embedded inside it, so "a"'s jar is an uberjar. Unfortunately, the version of "b" embedded in "a" has a vulnerability. The application's war file also has a new, not vulnerable, version of "b", as its own jar, inside the war file. So the application's war file contains two copies of "b": an older vulnerable one embedded inside "a" and a new not-vulnerable one as a jar in the war.
Can I know, without running the application by just inspecting the war file (reading the bytecode if necessary), which version of "b" will be loaded at run time? I want to know either that definitely the older vulnerable "b" will be used, so the war file as a whole has the vulnerability, or definitely know that the new version of "b" will be used so the war file as a whole does not have the vulnerability (although it contains the vulnerable code, it's unreachable), or to know the reason it's impossible to tell, because for example it depends on other factors.
As a follow-up, what is the recommended process of editing the "a" jar to remove the embedded "b"? Or do I have to build "a" from source myself?
I'm asking the general question because I want the general answer, but if it helps the discussion, "a" is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.9.2 and "b" is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.11.1

My suggestion: if a war contains byte code with the vulnerability at any nesting level, treat it as vulnerable. Being able to prove the opposite without actually running it would eventually run into the halting problem. And while in most cases you might be able to find the answer without solving that, I'm not sure that's actually worth the effort: Just build a version without the vulnerable byte code.
